# retrieving element from a list based on an element from another list

Tags: r, dataset

I have some data manipulation problem that I couldn't solve.

I have a list that contains BIC value from GLM model, basically I have 8 models, and I put each model into a list:

`spline_result <- list()
bic_result <- list()
for (i in 1:8){
    spline_result[[i]] <- glm(yy_01~sp[[i]][,1:i])
    bic_result[[i]] <- BIC(glm(yy_01~sp[[i]][,1:i]))

    }`

As you can see, spline_result is a list that contains 8 glm results, one for each of the spline combination. bic_result is a list that contains the BIC values from each of the model of glm.

Basically I want to extract the model (from the spline_result list) that has the smallest BIC values (but the bic value is stored in the bic_result list).

Could anyone comment on how to do that?  Also is there more elegant or efficient way of storing the model, and BIC (actually maybe not just BIC, but AIC, or other feature from the glm results like coefficient of estimate of certain parameters along with the model)  together in a dataframe? or storing separately in two lists is the best way of handling this kind of problem?

I would like have have the element in the spline_result list that has the smallest BIC value, because from all the 8 glm models here, I would like to extract the one with that has the smallest BIC and do an anova test with another model like this:

`anova(spline_result[[3]], lm(y~x_1 + x_2, data=da1))`

basically assuming spline_result[[3]] is the one that has the smallest BIC, and I want to do an anova of spline_result[[3]] with another model. So that is why I would like to extract the element (I think the element in this case is each of the glm model statement) from spline_result list and put that into an anova function for a comparison with another model. But before that, I would first need to successfully extract the model that has the smallest BIC.

Could anyone give me some hints how to do that? sorry that I am no familiar with advanced manipulation in R. I think apply, or maybe lapply could help. But I couldn't figure out yet.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for putting this on hold. I actually was trying to ask this on stackoverflow, but I was not "able" to post the question because I kept getting an error message of "it seems there is code" in your questions something like that, and it asks me to indent with 4 spaces, or use Ctrl + k, so I put the code inside Ctrl + k result (Ctrl + k gives me a single quote). So I put the code above inside the quote created by Ctrl + k when I was trying to post the question on stackoverflow, however it was not succesful. Sorry so that's why I posted here.

Comment: but I am still not sure how to post this question there on StackOverflow. I have posted many questions there with R code before, I was able to post my previous questions successfully even with R code in my question, but somehow this questions doesn't get successfully posted as I was not even allowed to post by hitting the "post" question button as there was some error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to store the BIC results in a vector instead of a list and then determine the location of the minimum.

I am not familiar with the output of the BIC function, but if it is a numeric, this will work.

Replace bic_result <- list() with bic_results <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 8L)

and  bic_result[[i]] <- BIC(glm(yy_01~sp[[i]][,1:i])) with bic_result[i] <- BIC(glm(yy_01~sp[[i]][,1:i])).

The location of the minimum value in a vector can be found with which.min function, so in this case we get which.min(bic_results).

The model with the lowest BIC values is then spline_result[[which.min(bic_results)]]